# App doesn't show the results I expect from an API call

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, token, retrofit2

Here's the repository
https://github.com/EnTusPupilas/Plantas/tree/master/app/src/main

I try to call this API
https://trefle.io/api/v1/plants?token=
through Retrofit but it does not show up on the screen.

I'm currently facing difficulties authenticating my requests to the Trefle API using Retrofit. I've tried configuring the authentication with different methods, including GET, HEADER, and PATH, but unfortunately, I'm not getting the expected results.